# "Imported content is empty" Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/1BxJl0Xz/", "//body/div/div/div/div/div/table/tr[3]/td/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div")
```

So i am trying to extract this information

[image] 
to my google sheets but i it just says that imported content is empty. Anybody have any idea how to fix this issue? :(

The path line i tried using inside my google sheet comes from this line in chrome console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work because that page appears to be using javascript to generate the content.

So while the xpath is valid (I'd guess since I checked on that page and tried this myself) the xpath doesn't actually exist when you use importXML because that will not trigger the javascript.

If you run wget or use the powershell below, you can browse the raw content and see that the values you see in a browser don't exist because no javascript is running.

(iwr "https://www.tradingview.com/chart/1BxJl0Xz/").RawContent | more

You'll need to do something else to make this happen.

Comment: I see. Alright thanks for the tip will see how can i work around this. But do u have any idea how to extract that information out to google sheets that works?

Comment: It's not possible to do this using IMPORTXML. There are other answers out there on how to scrape javascript generated content. You could utilize one of those solutions to generate your own web api to return the data you want from that page and then you could get it with IMPORTXML. It's also possible that tradingview.com offers some sort of API to access their data instead of trying to scrape it from the generated content.